# Changing Transaction Isolation level setting behavior in Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, transactions, sqoop, azure-synapse

We are currently trying to use Sqoop to ingest data from Hadoop to Azure SQL Data Warehouse but getting error related to Transaction isolation level. What's happening is that Sqoop tries to set transaction isolation level to READ COMMITTED while trying to import/export whereas this feature isn't currently supported in Azure SQL Data warehouse. I've tried using --relaxed-isolation parameter of Sqoop but still no effect.
As a solution, I am thinking to:
1. Change Sqoop source code to alter Sqoop's behavior to not set transaction level 
2. Look for APIs (if any) that may allow me to change this Sqoop's behavior programmatically.

Has anyone encountered such scenario? Looking for suggestions for the proposed solutions and how to go about them.

Comment: I can't help you with Sqoop but have you considered using Polybase to move data from Hadoop to Azure SQL Data Warehouse (ADW)?   That is one of its main use cases and a Microsoft recommendation for high-performing data loads to ADW.

Comment: We considered Polybase as a potential option but due to certain security issues, we didn't get endorsement from security team to use it in our context.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has just been resolved in Sqoop: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP-2349

Otherwise, @wBob's comment about using Polybase is definitely best practice: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-sql-data-warehouse-connector#use-polybase-to-load-data-into-azure-sql-data-warehouse

Comment: Thanks for the reference however I think the issue has been resolved only for metadata queries but not for all types of queries. I think import/export in Sqoop will still not work with this new patch.